# Set max count of duplicates

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like this...

```
    Name
------------
George
George    
George
George
John
John   
John
Paul
Paul
Arnold
.
```

and I need result with max number of duplicates. Forexaple max 2 duplicates.

```
 Name
------------
George
George
John
John
Paul
Arnold
.
```

How I write the script?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER`, for example:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Name)
         , Name
    FROM dbo.Names
)
SELECT Name FROM CTE WHERE RN <= 2
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c363f/2/0)</kbd>